# what should i do to send email to somebody without enabling "Less Secure Apps" in my gmail account?

Tags: python, email, security, smtp, gmail

Hello Guys This Is My First Time on stackoverflow

I Need A Help From You Guys That
I Created A Python Script Which Sends **Gmail To A Specified Person Using Tkinter lib And Smtp**
But **According To google's Requirement We Need To Enable Less Secure Apps To Be Able To Send Gmail**
But If I Start Distributing My Program Than **People Would'nt Use It Because Not Everybody would like to enable less secure app for my application** so what should i do? Please reply.

Comment: you cant do that without enabling it! Security matters and google ensures it!

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaVarghese But There Would Be Some Way

Comment: No.@JoshuaVarghese